# Finding statistically significant changes in a time series

Tags: time-series, change-point

What would be the proper way to determine statistically significant changes between time periods within a time series (between Yn and Yn+1)?   I thought about taking the first difference and calculating the z value for the difference value.

Comment: Please consider editing to say what type of change you're trying to detect, the nature of your data, and any relevant assumptions. As a general hint for finding relevant literature, what you're trying to do is called "changepoint detection"

Comment: Changepoint detection is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With provided details I think a self-extracting threshold model might server your purpose. If you are an R programming language user you can use `tsDyn` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/index.html). The `setar` function in the package can fit model to different regimes determined by significant change.